# Transistor Count vs Bit Count

Tags: hardware, processor-speed

When looking at the history of microprocessors I see that there is not a consistency with the bit count and transistor count of the microprocessors. For instance the first Intel 4004 was a 4 bit chip, but had 2,300 transistors. How is this possible? Maybe I don't understand hardware well enough.

Comment: this is not on topic

Comment: Where can I ask about hardware besides here and arduino?

Comment: you can ask about RPi here and about Arduino at Arduino site ...... try here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: `How is this possible?` .... how is what possible?...... your question actually makes no sense

Comment: What is the difference between the instruction set and the transistor count. I thought that for instance an 8 bit machine would have 256 transistors.

Comment: look up logic gates and transistors on instructables.com  (this is a good one: https://www.instructables.com/id/Logic-Gates-with-NPN-transistors/). You may also want to watch Ben Eater's youtube videos:  https://www.youtube.com/user/eaterbc ben his videos will explain and build a computer from first principles.

Comment: `I thought that for instance an 8 bit machine would have 256 transistors` following that logic, a 32bit machine would need 4 billion transistors, and a 64bit machine would require 1.6e+19 transistors!!!

Comment: so an 8 bit machine has 8 transistors and 256 possible on/off combinations?

Comment: No, you're completely confused, mixing up entirely unrelated concepts. "Not even wrong." But it's off topic for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your question is "on topic" for Raspberry Pi, but it strikes me as an earnest question, so I'll try to shed a little light. You'll probably learn a lot more by reading, and IMHO, still more by experimenting with the hardware... try to imagine how something works, then verify your theory by watching the bits change!

Anyway...

You're question hits on two different aspects of microprocessor design: transistor count, and addressable memory. Wrt the transistor count, relentless innovation in the industry led to an observation that's now known as [Moore's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law). Moore's Law says that transistor density doubles approximately every other year.

The second aspect of your question re "bit count" seems to hit on memory address space. And your observation is correct, addressable memory space has not gone up in accordance with Moore's Law. However, it's a different animal than raw transistor count, and it's progression is influenced by different factors. As processors have gone from 4-bit to 64-bit, what has actually happened is that the amount of memory they can access, or their *addressable memory* has increased. Hopefully, you can see that this is different than the number of transistors, although increasing addressable memory limits will always depend upon greater numbers of transistors. There's a fairly [good discussion of this topic on the Stack Overflow site here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869563/how-much-memory-can-be-accessed-by-a-32-bit-machine). You should read this.

A complete answer to your question is well beyond the available scope of this Q&A, but certainly you can develop an understanding and a working knowledge of these things if you'll expend a little effort. This will take some time, but certainly you'll be well-served by this knowledge, and won't get these miserable down-votes when you ask a question :)  A few links to get you started:

[What is a microprocessor (very basic)](https://electrosome.com/microprocessor/)

[What is "computer architecture"?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture)

[What computer architecture do modern computers use?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/which-architecture-do-modern-computers-use/24630)

As you may know, the Raspberry Pi is built on an [ARM Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture). You'll be in a position to appreciate its advantages (as well as its shortcomings) once you've spent a few years studying all of this :)  But even if you're only looking for a more basic understanding, a combination of reading and experimentation will serve you very well. And I feel that's what Raspberry Pi really has to offer - an opportunity for "the rest of us" to pull back the covers, and learn "what makes it go".